# Adding click event to KMLLayer Placemarks and Markers

Tags: events, google-maps, kml, google-maps-markers, google-earth-plugin

How do i attach an onclick event to Placemarks specified in the KML file. Can event listeners be added to both google maps and google earth plugin?
How would I go about this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**In the Google Earth plugin...**

```
google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function(kmlObject) {});
google.earth.addEventListener(kmlObject, 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var kmlPlacemark = event.getTarget();
    alert(kmlPlacemark.getName());
});
```

**In Google Maps API**

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.****.com/index.kml');
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
    alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly the onlick event is wrapped up when the kml loads (GMaps v3, kml with Placemarks) Any Placemark references to "BallonStyle" bundled in the same kml file causes these to replace the default popup - and you can achieve a lot with them.

These are the kml elements supported by Gmaps v3 http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html

If your question is how to intercept that onlick event, then I am sorry I do not know how you can achieve that.